# Correct use of alias in Interbase subqueries

Tags: sql, alias, interbase

I have a problem with my newly created aliases ABONO and CARGO. The ALIASES (for the column names of the result) and SQL query works fine UNTIL I try to calculate "ABONO-CARGO AS AJUSTE" => Interbase gives an error that it does not know the column "ABONO".

Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -206
Column unknown
ABONO

What is wrong?

```
SELECT M."MOV_CUENTA",
       (SELECT SUM(MM."MOV_MONTO") 
          FROM "movimientos" MM
         WHERE MM."MOV_TIPOMOV" = 'A' AND MM."MOV_CUENTA" = CS."ID_CUENTAMUN"
         GROUP BY MM."MOV_CUENTA"
       ) AS ABONO,
       (SELECT SUM(XM."MOV_MONTO")
          FROM "movimientos" XM
         WHERE XM."MOV_TIPOMOV" = 'C' AND XM."MOV_CUENTA" = CS."ID_CUENTAMUN"
         GROUP BY XM."MOV_CUENTA"
       ) AS CARGO,
       ABONO-CARGO AS AJUSTE
  FROM "cuentasSaldo" CS
 INNER JOIN "movimientos" M ON (CS."ID_CUENTAMUN" = M."MOV_CUENTA")
 INNER JOIN "ajustes" AA ON (M."ID_AJUSTE" = AA."ID_AJUSTE")
 INNER JOIN "documentos" DD ON (AA."ID_DOCUMENTO" = DD."ID_DOCUMENTO")
 WHERE M."ID_AJUSTE" IN
           (SELECT A."ID_AJUSTE"
              FROM "ajustes" A
             WHERE A."ID_DOCUMENTO" IN
                     (SELECT D."ID_DOCUMENTO"
                        FROM "documentos" D
                       WHERE D."ID_EMPRESA" = 1 AND D."DOC_EDITABLE" = 1
                     )
           )
ORDER BY M."ID_AJUSTE", M."MOV_CUENTA"
```

Comment: is it really required that u need to do a simple field1-field2 in query itself? Cant you do it in your application part? Aliasing the way u mentioned doesnt work in few dbs I know, so it has to be the case with FireBird too

Comment: Well, I am programming in C++ Builder and for I am using a TDBGrid (C++) component with a datasource and dataset to fill it I was facing difficulties adding a calculated field to the dataset. The __onCalcFields__ event of the dataset is not fired so I decided to let the DB do this part and calculate the charges and payments and its sum.

Answer (score 2):

Succinctly, in many SQL DBMS, the column aliases given in the select-list cannot be used elsewhere in the query, not even in other parts of the select-list.

You'll either have to do the calculation in a reporting tool, or repeat the two queries to get the value (which is painful to write, even with copy'n'paste — just one more reason to have a good reporting tool).

```
SELECT M."MOV_CUENTA",
       (SELECT SUM(MM."MOV_MONTO") 
          FROM "movimientos" MM
         WHERE MM."MOV_TIPOMOV" = 'A' AND MM."MOV_CUENTA" = CS."ID_CUENTAMUN"
         GROUP BY MM."MOV_CUENTA"
       ) AS ABONO,
       (SELECT SUM(XM."MOV_MONTO")
          FROM "movimientos" XM
         WHERE XM."MOV_TIPOMOV" = 'C' AND XM."MOV_CUENTA" = CS."ID_CUENTAMUN"
         GROUP BY XM."MOV_CUENTA"
       ) AS CARGO,
       ((SELECT SUM(MM."MOV_MONTO") 
          FROM "movimientos" MM
         WHERE MM."MOV_TIPOMOV" = 'A' AND MM."MOV_CUENTA" = CS."ID_CUENTAMUN"
         GROUP BY MM."MOV_CUENTA"
       ) -
       (SELECT SUM(XM."MOV_MONTO")
          FROM "movimientos" XM
         WHERE XM."MOV_TIPOMOV" = 'C' AND XM."MOV_CUENTA" = CS."ID_CUENTAMUN"
         GROUP BY XM."MOV_CUENTA"
       )) AS AJUSTE
  FROM "cuentasSaldo" CS
 INNER JOIN "movimientos" M ON (CS."ID_CUENTAMUN" = M."MOV_CUENTA")
 INNER JOIN "ajustes" AA ON (M."ID_AJUSTE" = AA."ID_AJUSTE")
 INNER JOIN "documentos" DD ON (AA."ID_DOCUMENTO" = DD."ID_DOCUMENTO")
 WHERE M."ID_AJUSTE" IN
           (SELECT A."ID_AJUSTE"
              FROM "ajustes" A
             WHERE A."ID_DOCUMENTO" IN
                     (SELECT D."ID_DOCUMENTO"
                        FROM "documentos" D
                       WHERE D."ID_EMPRESA" = 1 AND D."DOC_EDITABLE" = 1
                     )
           )
ORDER BY M."ID_AJUSTE", M."MOV_CUENTA"
```

It is rather easy to lose that solitary `-` in amongst those expressions.

Another way to do it is:

```
SELECT "MOV_CUENTA", ABONO, CARGO, (ABONO - CARGO) AS AJUSTE
  FROM (SELECT M."ID_AJUSTE",
               M."MOV_CUENTA",
               (SELECT SUM(MM."MOV_MONTO") 
                  FROM "movimientos" MM
                 WHERE MM."MOV_TIPOMOV" = 'A' AND MM."MOV_CUENTA" = CS."ID_CUENTAMUN"
                 GROUP BY MM."MOV_CUENTA"
               ) AS ABONO,
               (SELECT SUM(XM."MOV_MONTO")
                  FROM "movimientos" XM
                 WHERE XM."MOV_TIPOMOV" = 'C' AND XM."MOV_CUENTA" = CS."ID_CUENTAMUN"
                 GROUP BY XM."MOV_CUENTA"
               ) AS CARGO
          FROM "cuentasSaldo" CS
         INNER JOIN "movimientos" M ON (CS."ID_CUENTAMUN" = M."MOV_CUENTA")
         INNER JOIN "ajustes" AA ON (M."ID_AJUSTE" = AA."ID_AJUSTE")
         INNER JOIN "documentos" DD ON (AA."ID_DOCUMENTO" = DD."ID_DOCUMENTO")
         WHERE M."ID_AJUSTE" IN
                   (SELECT A."ID_AJUSTE"
                      FROM "ajustes" A
                     WHERE A."ID_DOCUMENTO" IN
                             (SELECT D."ID_DOCUMENTO"
                                FROM "documentos" D
                               WHERE D."ID_EMPRESA" = 1 AND D."DOC_EDITABLE" = 1
                             )
                   )
       ) AS X
ORDER BY "ID_AJUSTE", "MOV_CUENTA"
```

I think you should be selecting ID_AJUSTE too, but that's your decision.  I'm not sure whether you really need all those delimited identifiers, either, but I've largely left them untouched.

Comment: In Fireibrd quoted identifiers are only necessary if the identifier is a keyword or if you want case-sensitive identifiers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: so, in that respect, Firebird is standard SQL.  Standard SQL only needs delimited identifiers for keywords, case-sensitive identifiers, or identifiers that contain characters (such as spaces and dashes) that can't be in a normal identifier.

Comment: The first one at least executes, I think I just have to be careful for some accounts have <null> and so my sum is <null> For I am using test data and just a few accounts all sums are <null>. I am gonna check that.
The second part you posted does not execute in firebird => 
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 2, char 7
SELECT   (This is the SELECT after the FROM)

Meanwhile I will try to add a calculated field to the TIBDataSet...

Comment: Slightly puzzled; Firebird 2.5 supports the nested FROM (SELECT ...) notation according to the manual, and has done since Firebird 2.0.  All I did was take your query, indent it a couple of times, wrap parentheses around it, and add a new SELECT list and leave the ORDER BY below; and add "ID_AJUSTE" to the select-list of the inner query.  But take what works.

Comment: Oh, I got confused between two C++ projects. I'm sorry! This database is Interbase and in interbase I have to use a view or a stored procedure. I read for example here [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=552816) that this kind of nesting is not implemented. Is that correct?

Comment: Since there's a document about migrating from InterBase 6.0 to Firebird 1.5 and 2.0, it is a reasonable guess that the `FROM (SELECT ...)` syntax is not available in InterBase, which would be why the second query failed for you.  In which case, I suggest collecting the two values from your original query in your C++ program, and calculating the difference yourself in your program.  And an upgrade to Firebird, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a field ABONO in table "cuentasSaldo" (CS), and you have a subquery aliased as ABONO. So you have two "objects" with the same name.
I suggest you try to call field in format: query.field.
Example in Line 6:
instead of: `ABONO-CARGO AS AJUSTE`
use: `CS.ABONO-CARGO AS AJUSTE`.

Comment: I don't have any field called ABONO / CARGO. That comes from the table "movimientos" (movements) - Field: MOV_TIPOMOV: "A" or "C" => So this is not an ambiguous name but thanks anyway.